# Rally can I include iterations of child projects in IterationComboBox?

Tags: sdk, rally

I've built a story map cardboard with Epic swimlines and Iteration columns. There is an iteration selector that chooses which iteration to start from.

My project is a Child project in a portfolio. Each Child project has its own iterations. (Really we should align iterations and define timeboxes at the Parent level but we are not there yet.) Some Epics are local to my project, others are at the parent level so have stories in sibling projects too.

The apps works as intended in the child projects, ie it shows the stories in that project grouped by Epic and Iteration, starting from the selected iteration.

If it is run in the parent project it should show stories from the parent and all child projects grouped by Epic and Iteration (so the Iteration columns would be a mix of iterations from the child projects).

The problem is that the iteration dropdown doesn't populate when the context is the parent project. Without a selected starting iteration nothing else loads.

Is it possible to tell IterationComboBox to navigate down to child projects? I tried adding context:{projectScopeDown: true} to the config object but it didn't have any effect.

```js
        var me = this;

        var iterComboBox = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.IterationComboBox', {
          itemId: 'iteration-combobox',     // we'll use this item ID later to get the users' selection
          fieldLabel: 'Start from:',
          labelAlign: 'right',
          width: 500,
          listeners: {
            ready: me._loadSchedules,      // initialization flow: next, load schedules
            select: me._loadData,           // user interactivity: when they choose a value, (re)load the data
            scope: me
           },
           context:{
            projectScopeDown: true                              
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close- you had the right idea with that context config.  The iteration combobox actually takes a `storeConfig` property which will be used to instantiate its underlying store.  There is where you can pass the scoping information:

```
storeConfig: {
    context: {
        projectScopeDown: true
    }
}
```

Docs: https://docs.ca.com/ca-agile-central/saas/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.IterationComboBox-cfg-storeConfig